# Convert all pages of PDF to multiple png files with Inkscape Commnad line

Tags: pdf, command-line, png, inkscape

I'm new to Inkscape (commandline options).

I wish to convert a multi-pages PDF file to multiple png files (each pahe as one png file).

NOTE: Also need to maintain transparency.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I used following command to resolve my requirement.

mudraw.exe -r100 -o Paper.pdf_%d.png Paper.pdf

It worked smoothly.